# Send Image or Document with Inline Menu

Tags: python-2.7, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am coding an Python Telegram Bot with python-telegram-bot. I created a custom inline menu.

I want that the User could press a button and will get an picture. The `send_photo` function needs an instance of bot an update.

But I don't know how to pass that on to the `CallBackQuery` handler.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve it?

The send photo function:

```
def gvu(bot, update):
    bot.send_photo(update.message.chat_id, photo=open('botpic/gvu.jpg', 'rb'))
```

The Handler in Main Routine:

```
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(pattern="1", callback=gvu))
return self.callback(dispatcher.bot, update, **optional_args)
```

The error:

> TypeError: callback_handler() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chat_data'

Comment: can you post full error traceback?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
    buttonsMenu = [
    [telegram.InlineKeyboardButton("UP", callback_data="UpVote")],
    [telegram.InlineKeyboardButton("DOWN", callback_data="DownVote")],
    ]
    keyboard_markup = telegram.InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttonsMenu)
    context.bot.sendPhoto(chat_id=update.message.chat.id, photo=open('./imgpath.jpg'), 'rb'),caption='messageText', reply_markup=keyboard_markup)
```

This will send an image, with text and 2 butttons below the text msg.

Now for the callback query, i did this in main():

```
# Callbacks for the msg buttons
dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(vote, pattern="UpVote"))
dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(vote, pattern="DownVote"))
```

Where vote , is a def that runs the code i want for that callback.
hope it makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

Read into documentation here:

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinequery
https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/inlinekeyboard.py

Comment: there is no hint on how to upload an image inline